# Hyperledger fabric chaincode | Abstore Go application build giving permission issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to run a sample chaincode application on hyperledger fabric by following the steps mentioned in their github [url](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/chaincode-docker-devmode)

I am able to start the network using docker compose, below are the running containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
4992a3502034        hyperledger/fabric-tools     "/bin/bash -c ./scri…"   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes                                                        cli
4646e6ebf6c0        hyperledger/fabric-ccenv     "/bin/sh -c 'sleep 6…"   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes                                                        chaincode
c43bf3621a92        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start --p…"   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer
f0095379384b        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer
```

Now when I try to build the sample ***abstore*** Go application from within the chaincode container, I get the below error everytime.

> /opt/gopath/src/chaincode/abstore/go $ go build -o abstore go build
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/abstore/go: open
>   abstore: permission denied.

Can someone guide me here where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after giving complete access to the folders using :
sudo chmod -R 777 .